# CoreDataで Entityのアトリビュートをボタンを押したときほかのアトリビュートに紐付ける

Tags: xcode, swiftui

ボタンを押して、EntityのアトリビュートにほかのEntityのアトリビュートを紐付けるにはどうしたらいいですか？

Folder EntityのfolderName（String）というアトリビュートに
Text Entityのtext（String）というアトリビュートを紐付けるとしたら、

```swift
func doLink(folder: Folder, text: Text) {
folder.folderName = text.text
}
```

のようにアトリビュートにアトリビュートを代入すれば、できるようなのですが、一向にできません。

どうすれば、できますか？